# How to get mobile phone number inside Android application?

Tags: android, gsm, smartphone, sim-card

**I would like to know is there a way to retrieve a mobile phone number from inside a custom Android application?**

---

There is a class TelephonyManager but I could not see a method that reads GSM number from phone or SIM card.
**I have to add that it is not for any illegal purpose, customer wolud like to memorize GSM number of a client so he can get in touch with them.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Also requires the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to be in your manifest.